# R chisq.test giving different P-values

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm running chisq.test on some data, and I'm getting some unexpected results. Essentially, chisq.test is generating 2 different P-values on the same data. In the first instance, I'm viewing the entire output of chisq.test

```
chisq.test(a2_survey$Q3,a2_survey$Q4)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  a2_survey$Q3 and a2_survey$Q4
X-squared = 326.23, df = 25, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Alternatively, I'll just request the p-value,

```
chisq.test(a2_survey$Q3,a2_survey$Q4)$p.value
[1] 3.161995e-54
```

I have run this type of test in 5 instances (where I compare outputs), and it's only this one time where my p-value results are different from one another. Does someone have thoughts on why I'm getting two different outputs?

Thanks!!

Comment: The first case has a `p-value < 2.2e-16`, it doesn't have a `=` sign. Hence, it doesn't disagree with the second p-value.

Comment: `pchisq(326.23, df=25, lower.tail=FALSE)` has
`3.155362e-54`

Comment: @Suren, please post a version of these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `chisq.test(a2_survey$Q3,a2_survey$Q4)`  what you have is `p-value < 2.2e-16`. Which simply says that  p-value is less than `2.2e-16`.

The p-value is

```
chisq.test(a2_survey$Q3,a2_survey$Q4)$p.value
```

You may check this by using the `X-squared` and `df` returned by `chisq.test` as in

```
pchisq(326.23, df=25, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you Suren, I hadn't noticed the < symbol before (I've only just-started using chisq.test). I was under the assumption that the output was always '=' and not '<'. Thanks again for this!